# Vue anagram game which picks random anagrams from a json

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a project to create an anagram game in Vue. It should choose a random word of the correct length from the words in the anagrams array found in this JSON file. I can get the random function to work to provide a random word from the random array for length selected.

Json:

```
`{
  "anagrams": {
    "5" : [
      [
        "abets",
        "baste",
        "betas",
        "beast",
        "beats"
      ],`
```

game.js:

```
`export function randArray(arr) {
  const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  const item = arr[randIndex];
  return item;
}`
```

main.vue:

```
'<script>
    import SelectInput from './SelectInput.vue';
    import PlayButton from './PlayButton.vue';
    import MyScore from './Score.vue';
    import MyTimer from './Timer.vue';
    import MyGame from './Game.vue';
    import {randArray} from '../game';
    import anagrams from '../anagrams.json' 

    export default {
        name: 'MyMain',
        components: {
            SelectInput,
            PlayButton,
            MyScore,
            MyTimer,
            MyGame
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                length: [
                    ['5', '5'],
                    ['6', '6'],
                    ['7', '7'],
                    ['8', '8']
                ],
                wordLength: '5',
                screen: 'config',
                input: '',
                answered: false,
                score: 0,
                gameLength: 60,
                timeLeft: 0,
                anagrams: anagrams,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            config() {
                this.screen = "config";
            },
            play() {
                this.screen = "play";
                this.score = 0;
                this.startTimer();
                this.newQuestion();
            },
            setInput(value) {
                this.input += String(value);
                this.answered = this.checkAnswer(this.input,
                                                this.wordLength,
                                                this.anagram);
                if (this.answered) {
                    setTimeout(this.newAnagram, 300);
                    this.score++;
                }
            },
            clear() {
                    this.input = '';
            },
            getRandArray() {
                let array5 = randArray('5');
                console.log(array5);
                let array6 = randArray('6');
                console.log(array6);
                let array7 = randArray('7');
                console.log(array7);
                let array8 = randArray('8');
                console.log(array8);
            },
            checkAnswer(userAnswer, wordLength, anagram) {
                if (isNaN(userAnswer)) return false;

                let correctAnswer;
                switch(wordLength) {
                    case '5':
                        correctAnswer = anagram('5');
                        break;
                    case '6':
                        correctAnswer = anagram('6');
                        break;
                    case '7':
                        correctAnswer = anagram('7');
                        break;
                    case '8':
                        correctAnswer = anagram('8');
                }
                return (parseInt(userAnswer) === correctAnswer);
            },
            NewQuestion() {
                this.input = '';
                this.answered = false;
                this.array = this.getRandArray(this.wordLength);
            },
            startTimer() {

                this.timeLeft = this.gameLength;
                if (this.timeLeft > 0) {
                    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
                        this.timeLeft--;
                        if (this.timeLeft === 0) {
                            clearInterval(this.timer);
                        }
                    }, 1000)
                }
            },
            restart() {
                this.score = 0;
                this.startTimer();
                this.newQuestion();
            },
            computed: {
                question: function() {
                    const words = this.wordLength.words;
                    const word = `${words} ${this.wordLength}`;
                    return word;
                }
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Need more clarity. Can you provide an example of what the input and output you need the random function to generate?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How do I get the random function to work to provide a random word from the random array for length selected.